# Query on GlobalSecondaryIndex is missing table partition key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a table with a keySchema of object as HASH and id as RANGE, and a GlobalSecondaryIndex called dateIndex with a keySchema of artificialPK as HASH, date as RANGE

I can query the table using object and id just fine, but when I query the GSI using date and artificialPK, I get a ValidationException of a missing key schema element 'object'.  But that's not part of the index keySchema.

How do I query a GSI?  All the docs & examples seem to use just the keySchema defined in the GSI, but that's not working for me.  Am I missing something obvious?

edit: somehow the GSI has been declared with a different keyschema from the create_table command below, hence the problem.

```
>>> ddb_resource.create_table(
                TableName=self.table_name,
                KeySchema=[
                    {'AttributeName': 'object', 'KeyType': 'HASH'},
                    {'AttributeName': 'id', 'KeyType': 'RANGE'}
                ],
                AttributeDefinitions=[
                    {'AttributeName': 'object', 'AttributeType': 'S'},
                    {'AttributeName': 'id', 'AttributeType': 'S'},
                    {'AttributeName': 'artificialPK', 'AttributeType': 'N'},
                    {'AttributeName': 'date', 'AttributeType': 'N'}
                ],
                GlobalSecondaryIndexes=[
                    {
                        'IndexName': 'dateIndex',
                        'KeySchema': [
                            {'AttributeName': 'artificialPK', 'KeyType': 'HASH'},
                            {'AttributeName': 'date', 'KeyType': 'RANGE'}
                        ],
                        'Projection': {
                            'ProjectionType': 'ALL'
                        },
                    }
                ]
            )

>>> resp = self.table.query(KeyConditionExpression=Key('object').eq('foo') & Key('id').gt('0'))
>>> len(resp['Items'])
123

>>> resp=self.table.query(IndexName='dateIndex', KeyConditionExpression=Key('date').gt(0) & Key('artificialPK').eq('1'))
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: object

>>> resp=self.table.query(IndexName='dateIndex', KeyConditionExpression=Key('object').eq('foo') & Key('id').gt('1'))
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: date

>>> resp=self.table.query(IndexName='dateIndex', KeyConditionExpression=Key('date').gt(0) & Key('object').eq('foo') & Key('id').gt('1'))
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Conditions can be of length 1 or 2 only
```

Comment: The first one should work. Are you sure you're accessing the table and that the index has the keys that you expect, check the DescribeTable output.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Ah, the joys of working in dev.  Thank you!

Comment: So the issue still exists or the index didn't exist?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear. No, the index didn't have the keys I was expecting, yes the first one did work.  Not sure what to do now - do I delete the post because the question is misleading?  Do I mark your response as accepted because it actually solved the problem I had rather than the problem I thought I had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one should work, it looks perfect to me.

Are you sure you're accessing the table and that the index that has the keys that you expect, check the `DescribeTable` output.